# Como reproduzir som em um programa java?

Tags: java

Preciso fazer um programa em Java, em que o usuário coloque a senha e ela seja exibida em um monitor de TV, este programa vai ser utilizado em um restaurante, para que quando o pedido for concluído seja emitido na TV o número do pedido e emita um "som".

Como faço para incluir um som de alerta no programa?

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois está ampla demais a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Eu entendi que a pergunta final "como faço pra incluir um som de alerta" é o que o AP realmente deseja saber. Se for só isso, não parece uma pergunta ampla.

Comment: Alguém que votou para fechar, pode explicar o que está amplo demais aqui? Por sinal, votei para reabrir.

Answer (score 9):

Este é um exemplo em que o programa toca um som no formato .wav (a fonte é [essa resposta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13793955/2896619)):

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Carrega o arquivo de áudio (não funciona com .mp3, só .wav) 
        URL oUrl = new URL("http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-02.wav");
        Clip oClip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream oStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(oUrl);
        oClip.open(oStream);

        oClip.loop(0); // Toca uma vez
        //clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); // Toca continuamente (para o caso de músicas)

        // Para a execução (senão o programa termina antes de você ouvir o som)
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Clique pra fechar!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Esse sistema de áudio (`AudioSystem`) nativo do Java não suporta outros formatos, como .mp3. Se você tiver um .mp3 e não puder/desejar convertê-lo, pode tentar usar [essa outra opção com JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10237397/2896619).

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente eu tentei usar esse codigo acima e nao deu certo, usei somente o comando de loop pra repetir mesmo que tirei daqui, achei um outro que deu certo. Vou mandar aqui embaixo como ficou o meu.

```
package jogo;

import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class AudioAcerto {

        void AudioAcerto() { //Método AudioAcerto para chamar na classe executavel.
        try {
            //URL do som que no caso esta no pendrive, mais ainda é uma fase de teste.
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("G:\\ETEC\\2º MODULO\\4 QUINTA FEIRA\\PTCC\\EtecQuiz\\Musicas\\Urban-Future.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.start();
            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); //Para repetir o som.
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao executar SOM!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

A partir daqui é a classe executavel, a não ser que vão colocar o audio na mesma classe sem criar método.

```
package jogo;

public class Teste { //Classe executavel

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException { //Executável do jogo

        AudioAcerto y = new AudioAcerto(); // Chamando a classe aonde está o audio.
        y.AudioAcerto (); // Chamando o método do audio

    }
}
```